# DDD repositories with EF explicitly loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm starting to get my head into Domain Driven Design and I'm having some issues with the repositories and the fact that EF Core explicitly loading will automatically fill my navigational properties.

I have a repository that I use to load my aggregate root and its children. However, some of the aggregate children need to be loaded later on (I need to load those entities based on a date range).

Example:

1. Load schedule owners
2. Calculate a date range
3. Load schedule owner's schedules

I'm trying to keep my data access layer isolated from the core layer and this is where I have some questions.

Imagine this method on my repository:

```cs
public List<Schedule> GetSchedules(Guid scheduleOwnePk, DateRange dateRange)
{
   var schedules = dbContext.Schedules.Where(x => x.PkScheduleOwner == scheduleOwnerPk && x.StartDate >= dateRange.Start && x.EndDate <= dateRange.End).ToList();
   return schedules;
}
```

I can call this method from the core layer in two ways:

```cs
//Take advantage of EF core ability to fill the navigational property automatically 
scheduleOwnerRepository.GetSchedules(scheduleOwner.Pk, dateRange)
```

or

```cs
var schedules = scheduleOwnerRepository.GetSchedules(scheduleOwner.Pk, dateRange);
//At this moment EF core already loaded the navigational property, so I need to clear it to avoid duplicated results
scheduleOwner.Schedules.Clear();
//Schedules is implemented as an IEnumerable to protect it from being changed outside the aggregator root
scheduleOwner.AddSchedules(schedules);
```

The problem with the first approach is that it leaks EF core to the core layer, meaning that the property `ScheduleOwner.Schedules` will no longer be filled if I move away from EF core.

The second approach abstracts EF core but requires some extra steps to get `ScheduleOwner.Schedules` filled. Since EF core will automatically load the navigational property after the repository method is called, I'm forced to clear it before adding the results, otherwise I'll be inserting duplicated results.

How do you guys deal with this kind of situation? Do you take advantage of EF core features or do you follow the more natural approach of calling a repository method and use its results to fill some property?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I haven't touched EF in a few years, but the tt template used to generate partial classes for all of the data classes, so you could add methods which would persist across model updates. I used to use this capability to create implicit casts to logic layer classes which mirrored the data layer (EF) classes. So my query methods would return logic layer objects which didn't have lazy loading for navigation properties. Not sure if that helps at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider here.

Try to avoid using your domain model for querying.  Rather use a *read model* through a *query layer*.

An aggregate is a complete unit as it were so when loaded you load everything.  When you run into a scenario where you do not need all of the related data it may indicate that the data is not part of the aggregate but it may, in fact, only be related in a weaker sense.

An example is `Order` to `Customer`.  Although an `Order` may very well require a `Customer` the `Order` is an aggregate in its own right.  The `Customer` may have a list of `OrderIds` but that may become large rather quickly.  One would typically not require a complete list of orders to determine whether an aggregate is valid or complete.  However, you may very well need a list of `ActiveOrder` value objects of sorts if that is required for, say, keep a maximum order amount although there are various ways to deal with that case also.

Back to your scenario.  An EF entity is not your domain model and when I have had to make use of EF in the past I would load the entity and then map to my domain entity in the repository.  The repository would only deal with domain aggregates and you should avoid query methods on the repository.  As a minimum a repository would typically have at least a `Get(id)` and a `Save(aggregate)` method.

I would recommend querying using a separate layer that returns as simple a result as possible.  For something like a `Count` I may return an `int` whereas something like `IScheduleQuery.Search(specification)` I may return `IEnumerable<DataRow>` or, if it contains more complex data or I have a need for a read model I may return `IEnumerable<Query.Schedule>`.

Comment: I've been reading Julie Lerman articles on DDD where she creates domain models and then uses EF to map them to the database (whenever possible, otherwise use a read model). I've been following this idea and I create my domain entities on the core layer and then map them to the database on the data layer by using EF fluent configuration. From what I understood, you are saying that I should have repositories and a query layer and I should use this layer to get data from the database? What would be the point of Get(id) on the repository layer?

Comment: A repository should always work with a complete aggregate.  The repository returns a complete aggregate using the `Get` method.  That aggregate *could* be queried but probably is not going to be optimized for it.  For instance, when you show a list of `Order`s  then you do not want to load the `OrderItem` entries which is what the repository would do to constitute a valid aggregate.  Lazy-loading is, IMHO, an anti-pattern and indication that you are querying your domain model.  The query layer is much closer to the data and does not return domain objects.

Comment: So the repository would only deal with the domain layer and would not be related to any persistence stuff? I would use the query layer for that purpose?

Comment: The repository is used for persisting the domain objects.  The query layer is involved in providing "raw" data.  If you haven't done so perhaps you may want to take a look at command/query responsibility segregation (CQRS).

Comment: I've already some stuff related to CQRS, but never applied it in real life situations. Thanks for your help, I'll keep reading Eric Evans book to gain more knowledge on DDD since i'm trying to shift from a data-driven design way of thinking.